# c# перегрузка операторов

Tags: c#, классы, перегрузка-операторов

На пути изучения языка C# мне встретилась тема "перегрузка операторов".
 Вопрос такой : зачем вообще нужна эта перегрузка? Не усложняет ли эта примочка чтения кода?

```
public class coords
{
     public int X{ get; set;}

     static public int operator +(coords coord1,coords coords2)
     {
         return coord1.X+coord2.X;
     }
}

static void main()
{
    coords coord = new coords(){X = 20};
    coords coord1 = new coords(X = 40);
    Console.WriteLine(coord+coord1); //60
}
```

Лично мне бы читать такой код было затруднительно, вить более проще понять когда так:

```
Console.WriteLine(coord.X+coord1.X);//60
```

Просил бы привести пример, когда перегрузка операторов действительно полезна и нужна.

Comment: Где у вас в коде перегрузка оператора/ов?

Comment: А теперь добавьте еще Y и Z к вашим координатам

Comment: @LLENN Ах да, забыл дописать, извиняюсь.

Comment: @tym32167 почему бы для сложения координат не использовать отдельный метод? Например AddCoords(); <br> Так же проще и понятнее будет, разве нет?

Comment: Проще если ваш тип данных не должен содержать операций сложения. Но если, например, поглядеть на вектор. Операция сложения у него есть математически, потому при сложении векторов ясно что происходит, как и при умножении вектора на число. Или при сложении интервалов времени.  5 минут + 5 минут ясно же что дает. А вот если у вас какой то свой тип, например, накладная, и вы к ней товар добавляете — то это да, лучше отдельным методом

Comment: @tym32167 Более-менее суть перегрузки оператора мне понятна, Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ.

Comment: @tym32167 Что бы не создавать отдельную страницу вопроса - я его задам здесь.
 Например есть перегрузка для оператора + с параметрами (coords,int). 
 Если я напишу coords + 20 всё заработает. Но если я напишу 20+coords то я словлю ошибку. Неужели для всех этих случаев нужно отдельно перегруженые операторы писать?

Comment: да, так как результат выражения может зависеть от порядка выполнения операций. Например `1L + int.MaxValue + 1` - вполне легитимное выражение, но `1 + int.MaxValue + 1L` - уже грозит переплнением и в таком виде вроде даже не скомпилируется. То есть иногда есть разница. что к чему добавлять, А к Б или Б к А.

Comment: но в следующий раз пожалуйста создавайте отдельный вопрос, так как он не просто поможет вам получить отдельный ответ, но и также поможет отвечающим получить рейтинг за отдельный ответ. Ответы в комментариях никак не учитываются при просчете рейтинга, то есть, можно сказать, прося ответить вам в комментарии вы хотите получить ответ, но не дадите отвечающему заработать на этом рейтинга.

Comment: Кроме того, дополню tym32167, если создать отдельный вопрос, то в будущем его найдут и ответ поможет кому-то еще кроме Вас, а ответ в комментариях могут и не прочитать спустя время.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перегрузка позволяет Вам работать с классами более привычными методами:

например, пишите вы класс для комплексных чисел

у этих чисел также есть сложение, вычитание, умножение и деление, однако они (особенно умножение и деление) выглядят иначе, чем для обычных чисел:

сложение

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex z1, Complex z2)
{
    return new Complex(z1.re + z2.re, z1.im + z2.im);
}
```

в основном коде достаточно написать

```
z = z1 + z2;
```

И если Вы будете писать в основном коде умножение, как Вы предложили с координатами, то получите более сложный код - и как следствие - ошибки.
Перегрузив же умножение получаем на выходе простейшие действия в основном коде

```
z1*z2
```

где ошибиться гораздо сложение, да и читабельнее.

Одной из перегрузок является перегрузка операторов Equals, == и !=, позволяющая Вам заранее определить методику сравнения на равенство двух объектов. По умолчанию C# сравнивает на равенство с помощью функции Equals
определенной в классе Object,, а это значит, что два одинаковых объекта будут не равны между собой.

И это только самое простое, что мне сходу пришло в голову.

Однако, как указал tym32167 в комментариях, если у Вас свой тип с не столь очевидным сложением - накладная с товаром, документы (с полями хранящими создателя, согласующих и прочее) или что-то еще, то лучше создать отдельные методы, более очевидные при применении и прочтении.

Comment: Вопрос же не в том, что такое перегрузка. А в том, когда ее надо принять. И причем тут конвертация в строку?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо - со строкой я маху дал

Comment: В чем Вы не согласны в первой части Вашего комментария, я не понял.

Comment: ну, например, всегда ли `z = z1 + z2;` лучше, чем `z=z1.add(z2);`? Есть ли случаи, когда перегрузку операторов лучше НЕ использовать?

Comment: Спасибо. Но полагаю, что Вы ответили на этот вопрос выше в Вашем комментарии.

Comment: @Dejsving Ваш ответ - хороший пример для меня. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, но я не буду писать отдельный ответ, вы же уже половину ответа написали. Просто допишите остальное и будет полноценный хороший ответ на вопрос :)