# Перегрузка унарного оператора «!»

Tags: c#

Как правильно осуществить перегрузку и использовать в дальнейшем данный логический оператор «!». Если сравнивается следующие: если заданная дата(DateTime) день не является последним днём месяца то возвращается true, иначе false. Как перегрузить если это все в созданном классе и как этот перегруженный оператор использовать?(
Добавил код:

```
    public class DaateTime
    {
        private DateTime data;
        public DaateTime()
        {
            data = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);
        }
        public DaateTime(DateTime data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public static bool operator !(DaateTime data)
    {
        var day = new DateTime(data.data.Year, data.data.Month, 1);
        day = day.AddMonths(1);
        day = day.AddDays(-1);
        if (data.data.Day == day.Day)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Как мне теперь это дело вызвать из main? (если конечно всё правильно сделал с оператором)
Вот так:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DaateTime da = new DaateTime(new DateTime(2000,01,01));
            Console.WriteLine(!da);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так и использовать `!обьект`, но тут вас ждет сюрприз - вы не можете перегрузить sealed класс (DateTime - sealed)... Вам прийдется создать новый от `Object`, а что бы он дружил с датами - сделать implicit и explicit операторы (про них тоже можно почитать), плюс ToString подшаманить.

Comment: про перегрузку http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838676/c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: Я не считаю нужным присваивать оператору то действие, которое является вымышленым. Ваша задача в лоб не решается. Вам прийдётся написать класс зеркальный классу DateTime и вы столкнётесь с подводными камнями c# как неявный перевод в строку, implicit/explicit, вам прийдется написать более от 20 до 200 строк кода, ради одной мелочи. Я бы создал статическую ф-цию `bool xcheck(x DateTime)` и не мучался.

Comment: Задача не решается, т.к. DateTime защищен от перегрузки. Но если очень хотите  - создавайте клон. - 1)создаете новый класс, поздаёте поле `d`, создаёте методы и свойства такие самые как у DateTime - реализуете их через `d`, 2)затем реализуете implicit и explicit операторы 3) Подрубаете IFormatable - реализуете форматирование. 4) ну и ваш оператор ! добавляете.

Comment: @nick_n_a, DateTime - это структура

Comment: @Grundy а, да, точно, структура, но сути это не меняет. Перебить ей оператор так просто не получится.

Comment:  вот это вопрос я задал)

Comment: На кой фиг? Представьте потом как этот код будет кто-то поддерживать? Сделайте просто отдельный метод для заданой проверки, если уж очень хочется - можно сделать экстеншнш

Comment: Как писал Рихетр в своей книги "Перегрузка операторов должна быть очевидной". Сложение дат через "+"- это очевидно, а сложение каких-нибудь Person- результат не очевиден.

Comment: @iluxa1810, 5 февраля 1996 г + 16 мая 1998 г = ? Для дат нету операции сложения :) (можно сложить с TimeSpan, но это уже другое)

Comment: @iluxa1810 тем более для сложения есть методы, Add

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, что-то я попутал...

Comment: *если это все в созданном классе* - это что значит? Если у вас есть свой незакрытый класс (без пометки seal) то именно в него можно добавить оператор без проблем . Если имеется ввиду екземпляр от DateTime  - то я вам выше пояснил.

Comment: @nick_n_a да это мой созданный класс. В который я передаю дату какую-то. Далее необходимо было создать этот оператор. Я его реализовал. Но думаю что не совсем верно. Чуть позже выложу код, который получился. Столкнулся с проблемой использования созданного оператора.

Comment: Странно..........

Comment: @nick_n_a  извините, просто скорей всего моя ошибка есть. Я думаю будет ясно когда выложу код) извините, что не могу сейчас

Comment: Так я ж в ответе написал. Создайте екземпляр класса - и вызовите `!obj`

Comment: @nick_n_a, да спасибо, всё получилось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор для структуры `DateTime` переопределить нельзя, потому что она имеет пометку `sealed`. Унарный опрератор кастомного класса, переопределяется без проблем

```
public class Demo {

public class MyClass {
 DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
 // Переопределили
 public static bool operator !(MyClass a) { 
     return a.d.AddDays(1).Month != a.d.Month;
     }
 // Функция была бы так
 public bool e(){return d.AddDays(1).Month!=d.Month;};
// Можно свойтсво
public bool b { get { return  d.AddDays(1).Month!=d.Month;} }
}

public static void Main() {
   MyClass x = new MyClass();
   Console.WriteLine(!x); // вызов оператора
   }
}
```

Для унарных операторов - параметр один, оператор должен быть статиком.
С точки зрения ООП это тут нарушение, по-хорошему нужно что бы `!obj` - вернул такой же обьект в инверсном представлении, но среда не мешает вернуть bool вместо, и переопределить как угодно.

Мне кажется - само удобно - свойство. А економия в один символ - ну такое.

Comment: В ответе опечатка "seal",а не "sealed" или речь о другом?

Comment: Да, ни разу не использовал метку sealed, только видел...

Comment: _`a.d.AddDays(1).Month != a.d.Month`_ - странненько...

Comment: Чего странненько - последний день месяца:) Ещё плюс один день - и месяц не совпадёт.

Comment: А если перевод часов?)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - переводят в 3 ночи.